# Рандом из заданных чисел

Tags: php

Как реализовать рандом из заданных чисел? Нужно выбрать случайно число из этих чисел: 1, 55, 33 и 58.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array(1,55,33,58);

$answer = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
```

Comment: спасибо все работает =)